# Get entire table - MySQL error

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

Working with C# and MySQL here (Visual Studio 12 and MySQL workbench 6.1).

I'm trying to get the entire table into a list.

This is what I have so far:

```
List<Object> arrList = new List<Object>();

string str = @"server=localhost;database=test;userid=root;password=asd;";


MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);
con.Open(); 


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.CommandText = query;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
     arrList.Add(reader["* "]);
}
```

When I pass `SELECT * FROM emp;` for `query` and try to get a `toString` of arrList, I get an `indexOutOfBounds` exception. (My table `emp` has 1 record in it.)

Thanks!

**Edit:** I'm trying to get the entire table (sequentially) into a list. Is this the right approach?

**Edit 2:** What if we don't know the number of columns in the table?

Comment: How many columns has your `emp` table? Just one?

Comment: 2 columns. I want to go sequentially. Like [row1,col1] and then [row1,col2] and then [row2,col1] and then [row2,col2] and so on... **Edit** I want it to work for any table in the above mentioned manner. So we don't really know how many fields there are.

Comment: What are the types of these columns?

Comment: Various types but it's fine to get them all as strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     arrList.Add(reader["myColumnTitle"].ToString());
}
```

cause `"* "` isn't a valis columnname. alternative you can use an index

```
arrList.Add(reader[0].ToString());
```

for each Column:

List arrList = new List();

```
string str = @"server=localhost;database=test;userid=root;password=asd;";
string query = "SELECT * FROM emp";

MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str);
con.Open(); 


MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, con);

cmd.CommandText = query;
MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

while (reader.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var value = reader[i];
        arrList.Add(Convert.ToString(value))
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not possible to get the entire table (sequentially) to a list using this method? (Not just 1 individual field.)

Comment: All Data in a String? -> Select Column1 + Column2 from emp... Carfull about the datatypes. they have to be the same!

Comment: How about if the number of columns is not known?

Comment: Extended my answer. use reader.FieldCount if you dont know how many columns are available.

Answer (score 1):

`reader.Read()` read your results *row by row*. That means inside this while statement, you need to read all columns of your query.

When you write `"* "`, your reader looks for a column named `*` which you don't have. `MySqlDataReader` *can't* understand to read all columns when you write `*` as you can in an sql query.

This should work.

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     arrList.Add((string)reader[0]);
     arrList.Add((string)reader[1]);
}
```

If you *really* don't know how many fields that your `MySqlDataReader` has, you can use [`SqlDataReader.FieldCount` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount.aspx).

> Gets the number of columns in the current row.

So you code can be like;

```
while (reader.Read())
{
     for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
     {
        arrList.Add((string)reader[i]);
     }
}
```

Also use [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) to dispose your database connections and objects like;

```
using(MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(str))
using(MySqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
{
   ...
   ...
   using(MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
   {
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         for(int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
         {
            arrList.Add((string)reader[i]);
         }
      } 
   }
}
```